# How to predict the height of a jump based on gravity and jump speed?

Tags: physics

Alright, so I just finished with a simple tile-based physics engine, and one thing I am tweaking now is the appropriate speed, acceleration, gravity, etc. of the character.

Right now, I am having trouble determining how the relationship between `Gravity` and `JumpSpeed` affect the overall height (climax) of the jump. Here is psuedo-code for what I have:

```
physics loop:
{

    calculate new X position based on DeltaTime
    calculate new y position based on DeltaTime

    if holding space and standing on block then
    {
        increase vertical velocity by JumpSpeed
    {

    decrease vertical velocity by Gravity * DeltaTime
}
```

Alright, now say:

```
Gravity = 40
JumpSpeed = 10
```

How can I predict the maximum height of the jump?

Comment: Sorry, I may have just figured this out...

Comment: Would it be sqrt(Gravity/JumpSpeed)?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula?

Comment: You might want to consider asking the question on http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... or search for [Maximum Height of a Projectile](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-height-of-a-projectil.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution, y<sub>max</sub>=sqrt(Gravity/JumpSpeed), doesn't look right. It implies that strong gravity should *increase* the height of the jump, and high initial speed should *decrease* it. And the right-hand side of the equation has units of 1/sqrt(time), which doesn't make sense as a height. By dimensional analysis the answer must be of the form y<sub>max</sub>=k*JumpSpeed<sup>2</sup>/Gravity.

According to physics, the answer is

y<sub>max</sub>=JumpSpeed<sup>2</sup>/(2*Gravity)

But in your simulation, it will be

y<sub>max</sub>=JumpSpeed<sup>2</sup>/(2*Gravity) **+ JumpSpeed*DeltaTime/2**

Comment: Thanks! And by the way, am I doing this right? It seems that jumping and falling are slower when the framerate is slower, and DeltaTime doesn't seem to be helping.